# Ant scp todir with space symbol

Tags: ant, scp

I've got a task to copy a directory to the remote server. The problem is that destination folder contains 'space' symbol.

```
<scp todir="${admin_name}:${admin_password}@${admin_hostname}:/home/user/DIR HERE" trust="true">
<fileset dir="${DIR}/"> 
    <include name="server/**"/>
</fileset>
```

As result I've got:

```
[printStackTrace] /home/myuser/install/install.xml:39: server indicated an error: scp: ambiguous target
[printStackTrace]       at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:482)
[printStackTrace]       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:443)
```

It works fine when there is no 'space' in the path.
I've tried:

```
todir="${admin_name}:${admin_password}@${admin_hostname}:/home/user/DIR\ HERE"
todir="'${admin_name}:${admin_password}@${admin_hostname}:/home/user/DIR\ HERE'"
todir="'${admin_name}:${admin_password}@${admin_hostname}:/home/user/DIR HERE'"
todir="${admin_name}:${admin_password}@${admin_hostname}:'/home/user/DIR HERE'"
```

and many other variants, but it doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

The scp line gets parsed multiple times. If this was a standalone scp command, I'd recommend double backslashes before all spaces. You might have to triple backslash when part of an Ant recipe, but give both a try.

Answer (score 0):

You must put a backslash `\` before each space:

```
<!-- Escaping the space character with a backslash character -->
<scp todir="${username}:${password}@${hostname}:/home/user/DIR\ HERE">
...
</scp>
```